# LaTeX Companions Third Revised Boxed Set, The

Tags: books

I just found [The LaTeX Companions Third Revised Boxed Set: A Complete Guide and Reference for Preparing, Illustrating and Publishing Technical Documents (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321514432).

It might be time for me to update these LaTeX books of mine, but what are the differences between the first and second edition?

Comment: Two of the authors are community members so hopefully we'll get a definitive answer from them.

Comment: I know (and hope you are right). I'll ping @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: I assume (not that they tell authors anything) that the "2nd edition) here refers to the second edition of the latex companion. The 2nd edition (compass book) is much expanded from the first edition (the dog book) and has different set of authors (I wasn't an author of the 1st edition) 1st edition came out around the time of latex2e in 1994 I think, and the second edition was published around 2004.

Comment: See [**New to this edition**](http://www.informit.com/store/latex-companion-9780201362992) section of Description. Only that Boxed edition has all latest editions at a price advantage,you save better when you need all of them.

Comment: If it is the second edition of the LaTeX Companion "only", I have the newest versions of the books; thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: In general: Should I close this question, since there is no answers to accept?

Comment: probably close TL?

Comment: **TL** is Abbreviation of Too localised, See more at [meta.tex.sx Q](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/dictionary-commonly-used-english-acronyms-and-abbreviations-at-tex-sx)

Comment: Thank you! (I deleted my question, since I found the answer myself.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I forgot to ask: What is the latest printing of the 'compass book'? (I have the second printing from August, 2004.) Are there corrected error in later printings (if such exist)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg there have been reprints since then to fix minor errors, the full list of errors (and which if any reprint they are corrected) is at http://latex-project.org/guides/tlc2-err.pdf