# About The Latex Companion Second Edition

Tags: bibliographies

I need to learn Latex and I want to Know whether  The Latex Companion 2nd Ed. by Goossens et. al. is still up to date since it was written more than 10 years ago

Comment: Related: [LaTeX Companions Third Revised Boxed Set](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107413/) and [errata](http://latex-project.org/guides/tlc2-err.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

TLC 2nd is a great learning resource, albeit a bit outdated. One of its strenghts was to review many packages which at the time of its publishing were actively being used.

I would also recommend *[LaTeX and Friends](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html)*, by M.R.C. van Dongen (2012) or, perhaps more introductory, G. Grazter's *[Practical LaTeX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/331906424X)* (2014).

My personal favourite is *[A Guide to LaTeX and Electronic Publishing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321173856),* 4th ed., by H. Kopka and P. Daly (2004). (You can find a draft version at Daly's web site [here](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/homes/daly/GTL/gtl_20030512.pdf).)

You can also take a look at the celebrated *[Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/?lang=en)*, by T. Oetiker (if you've installed the full TeXLive distro, it's already in your system).

But I'm sure you'll find loads of other recommendations in the tex.SE pages.

Comment: @NVaughan.Thank you for the advise I will look for your suggestions however I meant an exhaustive reference like the TLC 2nd  Ed but more updated